# HTML button element height when I set CSS font: inherit

Tags: css

I faced a strange issue with `<button>` element. When it inherits font CSS property, it shrinks to line-height. I forced element to be inline, but it doesn't behave like inline. I expect that `button` element will be same height as `span`, because they are both inline elements.

**The question is why CSS property `font: inherit` causes red buttons to shrink?**

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.line {
  line-height: 100px;
}
.btn {
  background: red;
  font: inherit; /* WTF */
}
.btn1 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <div class="line"><span class="btn">Foo</span></div>
      <div class="line"><button class="btn">Bar</button></div>
      <div class="line"><span class="btn1">Foo</span></div>
      <div class="line"><button class="btn1">Bar</button></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: there is default padding/border for button ..remove them

Comment: button has default styles set by the browser, otherwise it inline

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? As far as I can see, the code is working properly.  Also you have no element with a class of line

Comment: I've updated example (it was wrong markup) and question text

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem.

```
.line {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

If you use "font: inherit;" on the button, it will get the "line-height" from the parent, from the ".line" element.

Try to change the line-height, and use other property like margin or padding to put space between the elements.